# MYSQL count (*) on multiple categories

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

What I'm trying to do is create a simple array that takes the sum of all my advertising clicks and gives me back a count for a simple ad tracker I'm writing. In another post on Stackoverflow read the following solution, but its not elegant.

Basically we are currently running 6 ads outlined below and we just want the count of those nearly organized into an array so we can do a do loop to show the ads.  Naturally it makes no sense to hard-code the count in SQL because we'll be adding more ads later. I thought about creating a do loop to go thru each count(*) and assigning it to a varible but that would cause us to hit the mysql server too many times than necessary.

Is there a simple way to transform this SQL statement into something we could easily generate in PHP.

i.e.  $ads = array ('money1','money2','money3','st1','st2','st3')

how would you get the count back out? is this the best way?

```
mysql> SELECT ad,
   SUM(ad = 'money1') AS ct,
   SUM(ad = 'money2') AS ct,
   SUM(ad = 'money3') AS ct,
   SUM(ad = 'st1') AS ct,
   SUM(ad = 'st2') AS ct,
   SUM(ad = 'st3') AS ct

FROM bloggingengineOptins
GROUP BY ad;
```

this is the output

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| ad     | ct   | ct   | ct   | ct   | ct   | ct   |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| NULL   | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|        | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    |
| 7230   | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    |
| money1 | 11   | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    |
| money2 | 0    | 12   | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    |
| money3 | 0    | 0    | 10   | 0    | 0    | 0    |
| st     | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    |
| st1    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 3    | 0    | 0    |
| st2    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 4    | 0    |
| st3    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 4    |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
10 rows in set

mysql>
```

After applying the 'fix' below the table now looks like this:

```
SELECT ad, count(1) ct FROM bloggingengineOptins GROUP BY ad;

+--------+-----+
| ad     | ct  |
+--------+-----+
| NULL   |  13 |
|        | 915 |
| 7230   |   1 |
| money1 |  11 |
| money2 |  13 |
| money3 |  10 |
| st     |   1 |
| st1    |   6 |
| st2    |  11 |
| st3    |   6 |
+--------+-----+
10 rows in set
```

Perfect output

Comment: It doesn't answer the question but why you don`t use `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: he is using, but wrong way

Comment: what does your table look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ad, count(1) ct FROM bloggingengineOptins GROUP BY ad;
```

Comment: That did it! wow - so simple and 'common sense' - the output simply worked exactly the way i wanted it to. thank you thank you!